# Máscara Jquery não funciona dentro de outro script Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, mask

Estou há meses quebrando a cabeça e nada.
Acredito ser algo relativamente simples, mas desisto que quebrar a cabeça.
Por estar a meses quebrando a cabeça, sou humilde em pedir ajuda, pois realmente dar uma solução para o caso.

Tenho uma tela que o botão adiciona mais inputs.
Nos inputs, todos eram para ter máscara de telefone, mas apenas o primeiro tem.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    var max_fields      = 10; //maximum input boxes allowed
    var wrapper         = $(".input_fields_wrap"); //Fields wrapper
    var add_button      = $(".add_field_button"); //Add button ID
    
    var x = 1; //initlal text box count
    $(add_button).click(function(e){ //on add input button click
        e.preventDefault();
        if(x < max_fields){ //max input box allowed
            x++; //text box increment
            $(wrapper).append('<div><input type="text" name="mytext[]" id="telefone" maxlength="15"/><a href="#" class="remove_field">Remove</a></div>'); //add input box
        }
    });
    
    $(wrapper).on("click",".remove_field", function(e){ //user click on remove text
        e.preventDefault(); $(this).parent('div').remove(); x--;
    })
});
</script>

 <script type="text/javascript">
  /* Máscaras ER */
  function mascara(o,f){
   v_obj=o
   v_fun=f
   setTimeout("execmascara()",1)
  }
     
  function execmascara(){
   v_obj.value=v_fun(v_obj.value)
  }
   
  function mtel(v){
   v=v.replace(/\D/g,"");                  //Remove tudo o que não é dígito
   v=v.replace(/^(\d{2})(\d)/g,"($1) $2"); //Coloca parênteses em volta dos dois primeiros dígitos
   v=v.replace(/(\d)(\d{4})$/,"$1-$2");    //Coloca hífen entre o quarto e o quinto dígitos
   return v;
  }
  
  function id( el ){
   return document.getElementById( el );
  }
   
  window.onload = function(){
   id('telefone').onkeypress = function(){
    mascara( this, mtel );
   }
  }
 </script>

</head>
<body>
<div class="input_fields_wrap">
    <button class="add_field_button">Add More Fields</button>
    <div><input type="text" name="mytext[]" id="telefone" maxlength="15"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Por favor, peço ajuda mesmo.
É possível que a máscara vá para todos os inputs?

Obrigado

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como você disse um erro simples, você está pegando o elemento pelo id, ou seja está tratando um único elemento, para tratar vário use classes, outra coisa, como está usando javascript puro para executar as funções, após criar um elemento dinamicamente a função terá de ser executada novamente, fica mais ou menos assim...

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>

<script language="javascript">
 
  /* Máscaras ER */
  function mascara(o,f){
   v_obj=o
   v_fun=f
   setTimeout("execmascara()",1)
  }
     
  function execmascara(){
   v_obj.value=v_fun(v_obj.value)
  }
   
  function mtel(v){
   v=v.replace(/\D/g,"");                  //Remove tudo o que não é dígito
   v=v.replace(/^(\d{2})(\d)/g,"($1) $2"); //Coloca parênteses em volta dos dois primeiros dígitos
   v=v.replace(/(\d)(\d{4})$/,"$1-$2");    //Coloca hífen entre o quarto e o quinto dígitos
   return v;
  }
  
  function classe( el ){
   return document.getElementsByClassName( el );
  }
  
  function masc(){
     var nEl = classe('telefone');
     for(var i = 0;i < nEl.length; i++) {
       nEl[i].onkeypress = function(){
    mascara( this, mtel );
    }
      }
  }

$(document).ready(function() {
    var max_fields      = 10; //maximum input boxes allowed
    var wrapper         = $(".input_fields_wrap"); //Fields wrapper
    var add_button      = $(".add_field_button"); //Add button ID
    
    var x = 1; //initlal text box count
    $(add_button).click(function(e){ //on add input button click
        e.preventDefault();
        if(x < max_fields){ //max input box allowed
            x++; //text box increment
            $(wrapper).append('<div><input type="text" name="mytext[]" class="telefone" maxlength="15"/><a href="#" class="remove_field">Remove</a></div>'); //add input box
            
        }
        masc();
    });
    
    $(wrapper).on("click",".remove_field", function(e){ //user click on remove text
        e.preventDefault(); $(this).parent('div').remove(); x--;
    })
});
  
</script>

</head>
<body>
<div class="input_fields_wrap">
    <button class="add_field_button">Add More Fields</button>
    <div><input type="text" name="mytext[]" class="telefone" maxlength="15"></div>
</div>



<script>
 masc();
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Opa Rogerio!

encontrei alguns erros no Codigo.

o Primeiro deles eh que só podemos ter um ID por pagina, o ideal eh usar uma Class para esse caso.

Outro problema eh que vc esta atachando o evento do teclado no documnt Ready, oq gera problemas para o Javascript entender Objetos Gerados Dinamicamnente.

vc pode entender melhor aqui http://api.jquery.com/on/
Caso precise "Brincar" mais com mascaras, Aconselho este Framework https://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/

Segue Codigo Corrigido

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

$(document).ready(function() {
    var max_fields      = 10; //maximum input boxes allowed
    var wrapper         = $(".input_fields_wrap"); //Fields wrapper
    var add_button      = $(".add_field_button"); //Add button ID

    var x = 1; //initlal text box count
    $(add_button).click(function(e){ //on add input button click
        e.preventDefault();
        if(x Remove'); //add input box
        }
    });

    $(wrapper).on("click",".remove_field", function(e){ //user click on remove text
        e.preventDefault(); $(this).parent('div').remove(); x--;
    })
});

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    /* Máscaras ER */
    function mascara(o,f){
        v_obj=o
        v_fun=f
        setTimeout("execmascara()",1)
    }

    function execmascara(){
        v_obj.value=v_fun(v_obj.value)
    }

    function mtel(v){
        v=v.replace(/\D/g,"");                  //Remove tudo o que não é dígito
        v=v.replace(/^(\d{2})(\d)/g,"($1) $2"); //Coloca parênteses em volta dos dois primeiros dígitos
        v=v.replace(/(\d)(\d{4})$/,"$1-$2");    //Coloca hífen entre o quarto e o quinto dígitos
        return v;
    }

    function id( el ){
        return document.getElementById( el );
    }

    $(document).on('keypress', '.telefone', function () { // Chamada para tratar o Atach d eventos
    mascara( this, mtel );
    })


</script>
```

Add More Fields

Comment: Deu certo. Obrigado!!